# How to create postgres extension inside the container?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have to install `hstore` to my docker postgres
Here is my ordinary command in the shell to execute my need

```
psql -d template1 -c 'create extension hstore';
```

If I remove that line my container, it works, but I have execute `hstore` installation by myself and I have to tell everyone in my project to do so which is not a good practice

Here is my `yml file`

```
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/devdb.dockerfile
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: uih
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: uIhbod!
      POSTGRES_DB: uih_portal
    ports:
        - "5433:5432"
```

Here is my docker file `devdb.dockerfile`

```
FROM postgres:9.5

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/postgresql-static/data
ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql-static/data

# psql -d template1 -c 'create extension hstore;'
CMD ["psql", "-d", "template1", "-c", "'create extension hstore;'"]

RUN echo "hstore extension installed"
```

After build I can not get it run

```
$ docker-compose up postgres
Recreating uihportal_postgres_1
Attaching to uihportal_postgres_1
postgres_1       | psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
postgres_1       |      Is the server running locally and accepting
postgres_1       |      connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
uihportal_postgres_1 exited with code 2
```

**Question:**

How to install `hstore` from the dockerfile?
I want to make an image and re-use it for the entire project for my team

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's failing because Postgres isn't running in the container during the build, it's only started in the `CMD` when a container runs.

The [entrypoint script for the Docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/b2317dd369030a5f3f030b1daa1fc80da3cab9e0/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh) has support for running setup steps - any .sql or .sh files in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory will be executed when the container starts.

So you can do this by putting your extension setup in a SQL script, and copying the script into the image in the init directory:

```
> cat hstore.sql
create extension hstore
> cat Dockerfile
FROM postgres:9.5
COPY hstore.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

When you build that image, the SQL script will be in the right place to be executed, so whenever a container runs from the image it will install the extension.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will back to computer as fast as I can. I am on the way home

Comment: Thank you Elton. I took me long time to understand your answer. I am new to Docker

Comment: This doesn't actually work if you're specifying a database up front via environment variables in compose. The docker-entrypoint-initdb.d files are run *after* `CREATE DATABASE`, so it only gets installed on the template (I assume) database, not the one you want. Not worked out how to get around this yet without actually specifying the database name in the sql file. Edit: though I've just re-reviewed the Docker image and it passes --dbname to psql, so I'm not sure.