# Postgres create extension command Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, postgis, pgcrypto

I need to create extensions for a Postgres instance running inside of Docker - specifically **postgis**.  I have followed other SO posts, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040540/how-to-create-postgres-extension-inside-the-container), to no avail.

Here's what I have so far...

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres
COPY ext-script.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

**ext-script.sql**

```
create extension pgcrypto;
create extension postgis;
```

Docker **run** command

```
docker run -d -p 5432:54323 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=somepassword -e POSTGRES_USER=someuser -v postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data --name dbcontainer dbimage
```

**logs**

```
docker logs dbcontainer
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ext-script.sql
CREATE EXTENSION
2020-02-20 22:18:01.090 UTC [60] ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
2020-02-20 22:18:01.090 UTC [60] STATEMENT:  create extension postgis;
psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ext-script.sql:2: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE

I ended up using the [postgis dockerhub image](https://hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis).

Everything is easy when you know how :)

```
# Dockerfile
FROM postgis/postgis
COPY data.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Answer (score 3):

PostGIS, unlike pgcrypto, isn't included in the default PostgreSQL packages, it needs to be installed from some source prior to calling `create extension postgis;`. There's a pretty good PostGIS docker container on docker hub [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/dockerfile).

Comment: Yes, I ended up going down that road but surely there's a way to copy the postgis binaries across?