# How to add scripts to image before running them in gitlab CI

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run a CI job in gitlab, where the integration tests depend on postgresql.

In gitlab I've used the postgresql runner. The issue is that the integration tests require the extension uuid-ossp. I could run the SQL commands before each test to ensure the extension is applied, but I'd rather apply it once before running all the tests.

So I've used the image tag in the CI script to add a .sh file in the postgresql image in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`, and then try to run the integration tests with the same image. The problem is that it doesn't seem to apply the extension as the integration tests fail where the uuid functions are used -- `function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist`

```
prep-postgres:
  stage: setup-db
  image: postgres:12.2-alpine
  script:
    - echo "#!/bin/bash

      set -e


      psql \"$POSTGRES_DB\" -v --username \"$POSTGRES_USER\" <<-EOSQL

      create extension if not exists \"uuid-ossp\";

      EOSQL" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-uuid-ossp-ext.sh
  artifacts:
    untracked: true

test-integration:
  stage: test
  services:
    - postgres:12.2-alpine
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: db_name
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  script:
    - go test ./... -v -race -tags integration
```

An alternate i was hoping that would work was

```
prep-postgres:
  stage: setup-db
  image: postgres:12.2-alpine
  script:
    - psql -d postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/db_name -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"uuid-ossp\";"
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
```

But in this case the client is unable to connect to postgres (i imagine it's because i'm editing the image not running it?)

I must be missing something obvious, or is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment i've had to do something a little smelly and download postgres client before running the extension installation.

```
.prepare_db: &prepare_db |
  apt update \
  && apt install -y postgresql-client \
  && psql -d postgresql://postgres@localhost/db_name -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"uuid-ossp\";"

test-integration:
  stage: test
  services:
    - postgres:12.2-alpine
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: db_name
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  script:
    - *prepare_db
    - go test ./... -v -race -tags integration
```

This isn't perfect. I was hoping that there was a way to save the state of the docker image between stages but there doesn't seem to be that option. So the options seem to be either:

1. install it during the test-integration stage.
2. create a base image specifically for this purpose where the installation of the expansion has already been done.

I've gone with option 1 for now, but will reply if i find something more concise, easier to maintain and fast.

Answer (score 1):

In both case in the job `prep-postgres`, you make changes in a running container (from `postgres:12.2-alpine` image) but you don't save these changes, so `test-integration` job can't use them.

I advice you to build your own image using a `Dockerfile` and the entrypoint script for the Postgres Docker image. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40043538/2653911) from @Elton Stoneman could help.

After that, you can refer your previously built image as `services:` in the `test-integration` job and you will benefit from the created extension.