# PostgreSQL: Create extension not working when called from init script

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'm using docker-compose to create a database capable of performing a trigram similarity search using the `pg_trgm` extension:

```
  postgres-db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:12.2
    env_file:
      - ../../.envs/_compose_prod.env
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ../entrypoints/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

**../entrypoints/init.sql:**

```
create extension pg_trgm;
```

I used `docker-compose down -v` first. Here's an excerpt from the output of `docker-compose up --build`:

```
postgres-db_1   | 2020-03-19 19:36:42.352 UTC [46] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-03-19 19:36:42 UTC
postgres-db_1   | 2020-03-19 19:36:42.360 UTC [45] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres-db_1   |  done
postgres-db_1   | server started
postgres-db_1   | CREATE DATABASE
postgres-db_1   |
postgres-db_1   |
postgres-db_1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
postgres-db_1   | CREATE EXTENSION
postgres-db_1   |
postgres-db_1   |
postgres-db_1   | 2020-03-19 19:36:42.643 UTC [45] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres-db_1   | waiting for server to shut down....2020-03-19 19:36:42.647 UTC [45] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres-db_1   | 2020-03-19 19:36:42.649 UTC [45] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 52) exited with exit code 1
postgres-db_1   | 2020-03-19 19:36:42.650 UTC [47] LOG:  shutting down
postgres-db_1   | 2020-03-19 19:36:42.686 UTC [45] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres-db_1   |  done
postgres-db_1   | server stopped
postgres-db_1   |
postgres-db_1   | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres-db_1   |
postgres-db_1   | 2020-03-19 19:36:42.757 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

It seems like the extension was created successfully. I have done this successfully on my own computer, so I'd expect it to work at this point, but when using `queryset.annotate(similarity=TrigramSimilarity("title", value_to_search_for))` and evaluating the query set in my Django REST Framework application, I get the following:

```
postgres-db_1   | 2020-03-19 19:36:55.384 UTC [81] ERROR:  function similarity(text, unknown) does not exist at character 146
postgres-db_1   | 2020-03-19 19:36:55.384 UTC [81] HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What can I do?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create postgres extension inside the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040540/how-to-create-postgres-extension-inside-the-container)

Comment: @iklinac I was already using the startup scripts folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [custom migration for creating an extension.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#creating-extension-using-migrations) That way it's not limited to docker or the environment.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import CreateExtension
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ...

    operations = [
        CreateExtension(name='pg_trgm'),
        ...
    ]
```

Comment: That works. I still don't know why it didn't work, but I don't need to anymore. Thanks!

Comment: @schillingt please which file I'm I meant to include the code you posted?

Comment: @toluwalemi You'd effectively need to create it like a data migration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations