# how to install third party extension postgres in docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

is it possible to install the extension in Postgres Docker Compose??
here is the list of extensions I want to install on Postgres

[image: list extensions]

The list is from https://github.com/supabase/postgres#extensions
they use Postgres 15 for that image, but my company's Postgres is 14.7, is it possible to install third-party extensions in docker Postgres for this?

here is the one extension i really need https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json.git

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create postgres extension inside the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040540/how-to-create-postgres-extension-inside-the-container)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. From the [official Postgres Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

> Additional Extensions
>
> When using the default (Debian-based) variants,
> installing additional extensions (such as PostGIS) should be as simple
> as installing the relevant packages (see
> github.com/postgis/docker-postgis for a concrete example).
>
> When using the Alpine variants, any postgres extension not listed in
> postgres-contrib will need to be compiled in your own image (again,
> see github.com/postgis/docker-postgis for a concrete example).

Alternatively, you can use Supabase's all-in-one [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/supabase/postgres) with Postgres 14. For example:

```bash
$ docker pull supabase/postgres:14.1.0.106
```

Comment: i dont want to use that image because they use postgres 15 and my project using 14, that is why I asked about how to add 3rd party extensions

Comment: that's exactly why I answered with the image tag `14.1.0.106` which uses Postgres 14